# CakePHP: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Post' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following code to show a list of posts that also contains information from the author user and profile. The profile table has no direct link to posts and is linked via the user table.

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = $this->Post->find('all',null,array('contain'=>array('User'=>'Profile')));

    $this->set('posts',$this->paginate($posts));
}
```

However I am getting this error:

```
 SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Post' in 'where clause'
```

Any ideas what's the problem here? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You're not supposed to `find` and then `paginate`; `paginate` itself calls the model's `find` method to get the rows for the current page. Change your code to this:

```
public function index()
{
   $this->paginate = array(
       'contain'=> array('User'=>'Profile')
   ); 

   $this->set('posts',$this->paginate());
}
```